# Stretch GridViewItem to fill screen

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm making an app that is similar to windows8 calendar app and I have ran into a problem.

So how to stretch my groups in GridView to fill all available space (the same as in month view in windows app)? I've tried to set property `HorizontalContentAlignment` of `GridViewItem` but it doesn't take an effect.

```
  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView Padding="116,37,40,46" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DayGroups}}">
      <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" />
          </Grid>  
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridView.ItemTemplate>
      <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
      </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </GridView.ItemsPanel>
      <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
          <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
              </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
          </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
          <GroupStyle.Panel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <VariableSizedWrapGrid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
      </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
  </Grid>
```

Thanks

---

ItemSource is just collection of

```
  public class GroupViewModel<TKey, TItem> : ViewModelBase
  {
    private ObservableCollection<TItem> _items;
    private TKey _key;

    public TKey Key
    {
      get { return _key; }
      set { Set(ref _key, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TItem> Items
    {
      get { return _items; }
      set { Set(ref _items, value); }
    }
  }
```

where `TKey` is `string`, `TItem` is `DateTime`

Comment: It would be easy to try if you add your c# itemSource code.